# Using git or Mercurial over a slow Internet connection

Tags: dvcs

I am working on a team of about 8 software developers.  The main team is located in a country with a very slow internet connection.  We are currently using SVN hosted on a server located with the main team.  Our repository is about 5gb and cannot be all transferred across our internet connection.  We would like to have developers work remotely and would like to convert to Git or Mercurial.  Once we get a copy of the repository to each remote developer how do we keep everybody in sync and how much bandwidth would be required.

Comment: I don't think we could answer how much bandwidth your team and project would require. "How do we keep everybody in sync" is not a clear question.

Comment: We use a VSAT connection and there is large latency times when transmitting and receiving data.  How does Git or Mercurial handle any errors in the syncing.

Answer (score 2):

git/hg should be bandwidth lighter than svn as it will only pull deltas once you get branches up to date.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139181/is-switching-from-a-cvcs-to-a-dvcs-a-considerable-bandwidth-save has got some great info.

Answer (score 0):

I think one key point to consider is that with a CVCS every developer has no choice but to contact the central server. With a DVCS one developer could pull/push changes over the slow link, and everyone else could pull/push from them. Well, I say "one developer", but it's really a single repo that they treat as a local master.

DVCSs allow you to create working practices that are far more flexible to work around whatever geographical or logistical issues you have.